# Region of most and least intense magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

It's a unmagnetized iron screw placed in the north pole of a U shaped magnet. I believe the region of least intense magnetic field is at the far left of the board. From what I understand the screw becomes magnetized and it's south pole is where it's touching the north of the magnetic, is it correct to assume the most intense magnetic field will be where the screw is touching the magnet due to there being direct contact between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Consider these images showing the magnetic field lines of a horse-shoe magnet. Magnetic intensity at any point in its field is directly proportional to its [magnetic flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux).So the region where the field lines are more densely packed have a higher intensity than where the field lines are loosely packed. If possible, draw the field lines for your own case and you will realize where the magnetic intensity is most and least.

Comment: There is a iron screw on the magnet, from what I understand that does make a difference on the magnetic field lines.

Comment: Yes you are right. The screw will have its own magnetic field which will increase the net field. But this increase depends on several parameters such as retenvity, permeability of the material of screw.

Comment: So there really isn't enough information to properly answer this?

Comment: The information you have provided allows for a conceptual study of the situation..what concepts are involved, what are the underlying phenomena. For exact mathematical results and details, you need more specifications as I have earlier said.

Comment: It doesn't need an exact mathematical results but an estimation of where I think the region of most intense magnetic field will be. On my initial post I assumed it would be where the screw is touching the magnet, can I make such assumption without knowing the parameters you've brought up?

Comment: Yes of course. You can say that without knowing the parameters you've brought up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30265/discussion-between-aniket-and-xsr).